# How to create a JSON array from below JSON with key-value?

Tags: javascript

Need to create below output from the JSON obj

```
let obj = {"id" : 1, "name": "John"};
```

expected result:

```
[
  {key: "id", value: "1"},
  {key: "name", value: "John"}
]
```

Comment: The key id, name are not always expected other values are also come in place let example:  obj = {"id" : 1, "name": "John", age: "28''};

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
JSON.stringify(
  Object.entries({"id" : 1, "name": "John"}).map(([key, value]) => ({
    key: key, 
    value: value
  }))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys of `obj` using `Object.keys()` and `map` them to objects.

```js
const obj = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
};
const result = Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({
    key: k,
    value: obj[k]
}));

console.log(result);
```